# Query on an entity, where joined with another that has a specific value?

Tags: ejb-3.0

I have a database with 3 tables.

```
LANGUAGE
id

ARTICLE
-id

ARTICLE_DETAIL
-id
-articleId
-languageId
```

I need to get an article from the database, but only if it has article details in a specific language. Today, I have the query in native MySQL using a coalesce, and that works fine. But now I want to make the same thing in EJB3. I've tried a lot of different things, but so far unsuccessful. I'm not very familiar working with entities in EJB3, so if anyone could please help me getting on the right track here, I would appreciate it.

Here's more or less what I've been trying so far:

```
Integer id = 543; // id of an article
Integer languageId = 2; // id of a language

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Article> cq = cb.createQuery(Article.class);
Root<Article> article = cq.from(Article.class);
Join<Article, ArticleDetail> details = article.join(Article_.articleDetailList);

// I think this is where I go wrong
cq.where(article.get(Article_.id).in(id)).where(details.get(ArticleDetail_.languageId).in(languageId));

TypedQuery<Article> q = em.createQuery(cq);
Article result = (Article) q.getSingleResult();
return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job:

```
...
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Article> cq = cb.createQuery(Article.class);
Root<Article> article = cq.from(Article.class);
Join<Article, ArticleDetail> details = article.join(Article_.articleDetailList);
Join<ArticleDetail, Language> language = details.join(ArticleDetail_.languageId);
cq.where(cb.and(
  cb.equal(article.get(Article_.id), id),
  cb.equal(language.get(Language_.id), languageId)));
...
```